# How can a worker thread ask the main thread to create/show a dialog box

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a main thread running as well as a couple of worker threads.

From the main thread I sometime show one or more modeless dialog boxes.

But now I would like the worker threads themselves to 'create' the dialog box.
From what I read here and on the internet, all the GUI display/dialogs should be managed by the main thread and not by the worker threads.

But how should I get the worker thread to ask the main thread to display a dialog box?

Comment: PostMessage() is one way.

Comment: Send a message containing the dialog box parameters to the main thread. PostMessage is one of the most reasonable of many options. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, and I would post back the result to the worker thread when done?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "inter thread communication", it should give you a bunch of hits.